Why is randint seemingly not uniformly distributed?
Consider the code:
from random import randint
from math import log10

print(log10(sum([randint(0, 1e12) for _ in range(int(1e6))]) / 1e6))

I believe the result should be close to 11, but instead the output is: 11.699144269464252
Some context:
root@debian:~# python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
root@debian:~# uname -a
Linux debian 6.1.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.85-1 (2024-04-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux


Why do you believe that the result should be close to 11? Which result do you expect exactly?

The result you expect does not actually make sense (if you did get a result close to 11, it would be very strong evidence against a uniform distribution), and the actual result does make sense, and the reason for that is a math question, not a programming question. Hint: what result would you expect if the upper limit were instead 1e1 (i.e. 10)? (Hint for the hint: what is the expected average result for that input range? What is the base-10 logarithm of that result?)

@mkrieger1 Of course an exact result is not expected at all, because the input is inherently random. But OP is simply mistaken about the underlying math. (The reasoning implied by this expectation, works in base 2, not in base 10.)

The expected value for sum([randint(0, 1e12) for _ in range(n)]) / n) is 1e12 / 2 if randint is uniformly distributed and n is large.
So the expected result should be log10(1e12 / 2) which is 11.698970004336019, which is "pretty close"1 to what you got.
So the result you got does not indicate that randint is not uniformly distributed.

1What "close" even means is a statistics/probability question and is out of scope for this site.
